# DSN Entries created by in ODBCCP32.dll does not show up in regedit

Tags: c#, registry, dsn

I used a function in ODBCCP32 to create a dsn entry.

The entry was created successfully and could be viewed using odbcca32.exe.

However, when I used regedit and went to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI, I did not see it there.

This is the function I used:

```
[DllImport("ODBCCP32.dll")]
private static extern bool SQLConfigDataSource(IntPtr hwndParent, int fRequest, string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);
```

I had a wrap up method to call it:

```
public static bool CreateDataSource(string ODBC_Driver, string DataSourceName, string DatabasePath)
{
    return SQLConfigDataSource((IntPtr)0, ODBC_Request_Modes.ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, ODBC_Driver, "DSN=" + DataSourceName);}
```

The request modes and drivers were declared below:

```
public static class ODBC_Drivers
{
    public static string SQL11 = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0";
}
public static class ODBC_Request_Modes
{
    public static int ODBC_ADD_DSN                      = 1;
    public static int ODBC_CONFIGD_DSN              = 2;
    public static int ODBC_REMOVE_DSN                   = 3;
    public static int ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN              = 4;
    public static int ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN           = 5;
    public static int ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN           = 6;
    public static int ODBC_REMOVE_DEFAULT_DSN = 7;
}
```

Note: the program in C# successfully created the dsn entry but it did not write in the registry, as a result, I can not save the credentials there.

Do you see anything flaring at you?

Thanks!

Comment: If the function did not fail and you can even view it then you *know* that the registry entries exist.  You just haven't found them back yet.  Other places where ODBC config could be stored is in Wow6432Node for 32-bit processes and HKCU for non-system DSNs.  Probably the latter.  Consider using Regedit's Edit > Find command and SysInternals' Process Monitor to observe your program writing to the register.

Comment: @HansPassant: You are absolutely right! They are under Wow6431Node!! Please make it a formal response so that I can accept it if you do not mind. One thing I do not quite understand is why HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI does have other entries that gave me the wrong impression that it was not created. Another concern/question is the password field does not stick. The dsn entry is needed for vendors to access the database, if it does not stick, do I need to share the password with them? Or does the system save the password somewhere else hidden but can retrieve it when needed?